# How to Display Json Response using get method

Tags: ios, json, swift, get

Here is my Response and I want to print the response using array I want to take some details in the response like "Id" and "available" and "leaves"  and I have to show in a label in my VC

```
{
"id": 1,
"emp_id": "001",
"termination_date": "active",
"blood_group": "A+",
"rating": 0,
"noOfStars": 0,
"starOfMonth": false,
"gender": "Female",
"expertise": "",
"experience": "",
"leaves": 0,
"available": 5,
"compoff": 0,
"earnedLeaves": null,
"wfh": 0
```

}

my code is

```
struct jsonstruct8:Decodable  {

var available: String
var leaves: String
```

}

```
var arrdata = [jsonstruct8]()


func getdata(){
    let url = URL(string: "MY URL")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error )in
        do{if error == nil{

            self.arrdata = try JSONDecoder().decode([jsonstruct8].self, from: data!)

            for mainarr in self.arrdata{
            print(mainarr.available,":",mainarr.leaves)
            print(data)
            }
            }

        }catch{
            print("Error in get json data")
        }

        }.resume()
}
```

I am getting "Error in get json data"

Comment: The JSON you've added is not an array. Add the whole valid JSON here.

Comment: Also, add the Codable model that you're using.

Comment: _"I am getting "Error in get json data"_, that's because you have hard coded that error message. Do `print(error)` instead so that you get the real error printend

Comment: @ PGDev I have Updated my Question please check

Comment: This is the error I am getting.                                    typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: And there's your answer, it's not an array but a dictionary. Change `[jsonstruct8].self` to `jsonstruct8.self`

Comment: ya I resolved that issue @ Joakim     thanks you and please help me how to assign that value to a label in my view controller I am unable to assign directly

Comment: self.totalLeaves.text = "\(mainarr.available)"
  self.usedLeavesLbl.text = "/ \(mainarr.leaves)".   I am assigning like this to labels and parameters are declared in Int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample JSON:**

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "emp_id": "001",
    "termination_date": "active",
    "blood_group": "A+",
    "rating": 0,
    "noOfStars": 0,
    "starOfMonth": false,
    "gender": "Female",
    "expertise": "",
    "experience": "",
    "leaves": 0,
    "available": 5,
    "compoff": 0,
    "earnedLeaves": null,
    "wfh": 0
  }
```

**Model:**

```
struct Employee: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let empId: String
    let terminationDate: String
    let available: Int
    let leaves: Int
    //add other properties as well....
}
```

**Parsing:**

```
if let data = data {
    if let data = data {
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            var employee = try JSONDecoder().decode(Employee.self, from: data)
            print("\(employee.available) : \(employee.leaves)") //here you can modify then employee details...
        } catch  {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Always update the UI on *main thread*.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.totalLeaves.text = "\(employee.leaves)"
}
```

Comment: I am getting this compile error  .  Value of type 'JSONDecoder' has no member 'keyDecodingStrategy'

Comment: my response is starting with an object not with an array sorry I forgot to mention

Comment: Updated the answer for object instead of array.

Comment: I am trying your code but getting  this compile error     "Value of type 'JSONDecoder' has no member 'keyDecodingStrategy' "         for this line code          decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase.       I am using swift 4 Xcode 9.2

Comment: yes I figured that and help me how to assign that parameters (Int )value to UILabel  I am unable to assign it

Comment: `self.totalLeaves.text = "\(employee.leaves)"` Here is how you can assign values to your label using the object.

Comment: yes I did same but getting error as
  Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UILabel setText:]

Comment: yes yes I missed the  DispatchQueue its  working Thanks